# e-gold VAP - safe to use?

Tags: united-states, gold

Some years ago, I created an [e-gold](http://e-gold.com/) account and transferred some gold into it. e-gold's service has been suspended in 2009 for legal issues. Now, they offer a VAP ("Value Access Plan") to let me obtain dollars worth the amount of gold in my account.

The catch: As a German citizen, I have to specify my *full address*, my *date of birth*, my *personal tax ID*, and submit a *copy of my photo ID* as well as a *proof of residence*.

Is it safe to do that, i.e. will that associate my data with a criminal organization? In particular, if I ever want to become a US resident, will that put me at a disadvantage?

Comment: You should be paranoid in general about giving out personal infomation, but you are way over the top. I believe they are playing it safe and confirming everybody's identity before dishing out the money, so they don't get fleeced and get into any legal trouble later.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-gold, e.g. *"[...] they are legally required to perform various sorts of "know your customer" background checks"* and *"e-gold initiated a value access plan that was approved by relevant governmental authorities in the U.S. Users would have access to the value in their accounts after submitting additional information to e-gold, and after a review of this information by the Court-appointed Claims Administrator and the U.S. Government."* Have you perhaps checked with the Claims Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting Chris W. Rea's comment into an answer

See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-gold, e.g. "[...] they are legally required to perform various sorts of "know your customer" background checks" and "e-gold initiated a value access plan that was approved by relevant governmental authorities in the U.S. Users would have access to the value in their accounts after submitting additional information to e-gold, and after a review of this information by the Court-appointed Claims Administrator and the U.S. Government."

Please verify with the Clamins Administrator

Comment: Eventually I participated in the claims process and [got reimbursed about a month ago](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/22896/9575).

Comment: @feklee: Congrats. Looks like alls well at the end.