# ACH data for Deutsche Bank, Germany?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, international-transfer, germany

For an international ACH transfer as part of the [e-gold claims process](https://egoldclaimsprocess.com/), I need to specify in an online form:

- Financial Institution Name
- Financial Institution Address
- Financial Institution City
- Financial Institution State/Province Code
- Financial Institution Postal Code
- Financial Institution Country: GERMANY - DE *(prefilled)*
- ACH Coordinator at Financial Institution
- ACH Coordinator Telephone Number
- Bank Identification/Routing Number
- Account Title

*What is the correct data for [Deutsche Bank](http://www.deutsche-bank.de), Germany?*

I already called customer service of Deutsche Bank, but they did not even know what ACH is. I also sent them a message via their online banking web interface (confirmed by a TAN, so it should get read).

Screenshot of the complete form:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: > While some institutions may ask to provide both SWIFT-BIC and IBAN,
> generally it isn't needed - IBAN already includes full routing
> information, and the BIC can be automatically determined from the
> IBAN. – Peteris Mar 6 at 2:49 This isn't exactly true, my bank here in Germany uses a different bank for foreign currency processing. As such, non-EUR currency transfers (eg, sending USD to USD denominated account) must go through a different BIC than what you'll get if you punch in my IBAN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I called Deutsche Bank. They said that for an international
transfer I need to specify IBAN and SWIFT-BIC. The ACH specific
information is irrelevant.

Later I called e-gold claims process customer service, +1.8887647519:

- *"ACH Coordinator at Financial Institution", "ACH Coordinator
  Telephone Number":* Just a contact at the bank, in case there are
  questions.
- *"Bank Identification/Routing Number":* I proposed entering the
  SWIFT-BIC code, explaining briefly what it is. The customer service
  representative agreed.
- *"Account Title":* I said that my bank told me that there is no such
  thing as an account title, and I proposed to just enter my name. The
  representative agreed.

I then called Deutsche Bank again, and they named me a random contact
person at a local office. They said that normally this information is
not necessary.

In a nutshell: This form was designed by idiots. One part is plain
wrong: With a radio button, one has to select either BIC *or* IBAN, where
the BIC code is not an account number. It identifies a bank.

**Update**: On of 2014-01-16 CET, I received the money to my Deutsche Bank account.

Comment: While some institutions may ask to provide both SWIFT-BIC and IBAN, generally it isn't needed - IBAN already includes full routing information, and the BIC can be automatically determined from the IBAN.

Comment: @Peteris Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: So thay acually needed 7 months for this transfer? That's quite a lot.

Comment: @glglgl I don't remember exactly. Apparently it took a while until the entity in charge of the claims process initiated the transfer. All international transfers to and from my bank account took no more than a few days.